# iOS - Target not displaying while adding new file

Tags: ios, file, cocoa, target

After merging code, When i tried to add a new file, xCode is not displaying targets to select. Also after adding file, its not showing targets to get selected.

Referenced image is added. Please help to find the root cause and solution of the problem.

Comment: In build phases you can add directly to compile sources

Answer (score 0):

You could add the resources/images to target as shown in below screenshot.

[image: Add resource to target]